# Using the replicate function in haskell to add to a list

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I'm to use the replicate function that Haskell has (`replicate 3 'x' = ['x','x','x']`) but I'm trying to add it to a list that already exists.

```
Prelude > let k = ['d','f','g']
Prelude > (replicate 3 'd':k)
```

but I keep getting the error,

```
Couldn't match type 'Char' with '[Char]'
Expected type: [[Char]]
Actual type: [Char]
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`k` and `replicate 3 'd'` each have a type of `[Char]`.

```
ghci> :t k
k :: [Char]

ghci> :t replicate 3 'd'
replicate 3 'd' :: [Char]
```

However, the type of `(:)` is `a -> [a] -> [a]`: it takes a single `a` and adds it to the list of `a`s.

```
ghci> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

So Haskell's giving you a type error because you can't apply `(:)` to two things of type `[Char]`. In other words, you can't put a `[Char]` inside a `[Char]`.

What we really need is a function of type `[a] -> [a] -> [a]` which concatenates the two lists. It happens that this function is called `(++)`.

```
ghci> :t (++)
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]

ghci> replicate 3 'd' ++ k
"ddddfg"
```